# run a method in an element of an Arraylist in java

Tags: java

I want to know if there's a way to run a method of inside an element of an Arraylist
but I don't want to do it with get because it actually changes fields of the element

thanks
benny.

Comment: Didn't quite get the question. How does ArrayList.get() changes your element? It does nothing, just gets the element and returns it to you, it does no changes to the element itself. So you would be able to do: list.get(5).myFunction(). So, please clarify what you need and why.

Comment: ok, I think I wasn't clear, what I need is a pointer I do need to change the element.
what get method gives is a copy of the element and I need a pointer

Comment: List.get() does not give you a copy, it gives you a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make everything even more clear than all the comments did:

```
public class ReferenceTester {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String original = "The One and only one";
        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(original);
        final String copy = list.get(0);
        if (original == copy) {
            System.out.println("Whoops, these are actually two references to the same object.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("References to a different objects? A copy?");
        }
    }

}
```

Run this class and see what it prints.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to do it with `get` as in `yourList.get(5).someMethod()`?

The `get` method will not "extract" the element it returns, it will only return a copy of the reference. Getting + removing is the implementaiton of `remove`.

So, unless you have overridden the `get` method it will *not* modify the list.

---

Update and clarification:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(myObject);         // add a reference to myObject in the list
                            // (remember, you can't pass around objects in java)
list.get(0).someMethod();   // get a copy of that reference and call someMethod()
```

Comment: what the get method returns is a copy of the element and I need a pointer

Comment: It doesn't return a copy.  It returns the the same reference you put in.

Comment: No. In java, you never pass around objects, only references. So, no worries, you'll get a "pointer".

Comment: No it doesn't. It returns a reference (pointer) to the same object.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen. Actually, it does return a copy. It returns a copy of what you put in. But since you put in a reference ("pointer") to the object, that is what you get a copy of.

Comment: @aioobe, whilst that it 100% true, it's unlikely to help an obvious newbie understand what's going on.

Comment: @Danny, you think? That's what messed my head up the first months I worked with java. (I had a c/c++ background too.) In a nutshell java is *always call by value* and *only access through references*. If one keeps that in mind, everything is clear I think :-)

Comment: @aioobe: Correct. Just understand the fundamentals, and everything else is explainable by it. In that sense, things are actually quite simpler in Java. Which was the intent.

Comment: @aioobe: this comes up all the time on the Sun Java forums. By far the best way of explaining it to people with a C/C++ background is just to say that everything is pointers. Saying that you pass references by value, whilst strictly correct, just confuses people, IMHO.